# Impossible to connect to Postgresql using RubyMine

Tags: postgresql, rubymine

I've been trying to connect to **PostgreSQL** using **RubyMine** but it's always asking for a password.

In a terminal I do connect using:

```
psql -U postgres
```

I don't have to input a password.

But, when I tried using RubyMine to connect to PostgreSQL is always asking for a password. I tried input some passwords but they don't work. Any idea?

My settings file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: portafolio_development
  username: postgres
  password:

test:
  <<: *default
  database: portafolio_test
  username: postgres
  password:

production:
  <<: *default
  database: portafolio_production
  username: portafolio
  password: <%= ENV['PORTAFOLIO_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

**Edited**

My **pg_hba.conf**:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

**Solved**

Result that I have two `pg_hba.conf` files. One for version *9.3* and another for *9.4*. I changed the first one to the following and everything is working now:

```
local all postgres trust
# The same using local loopback TCP/IP connections.
#
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

# The same as the previous line, but using a separate netmask column
#
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            IP-ADDRESS      IP-MASK             METHOD
host    all             all             127.0.0.1       255.255.255.255     trust

# The same over IPv6.
#
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

# The same using a host name (would typically cover both IPv4 and IPv6).
#
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             localhost               trust
```

Comment: Could you show us your settings for pg_hba.conf ?

Comment: Do you have a ~/.pgpass file?

Comment: @GabrielMuñumel: No, you don't strictly *need* one. When you use `psql -U postgres` which database do you connect to? (It will appear in the prompt.)

Comment: it shows `postgres=#`. For example, if I run `\l` I can see all the tables.

Comment: I'd try `psql -U postgres portafolio_development`, then the other two databases. What operating system?

Comment: I solved the problem, was a problem with my `pg_hba.conf`. Result that I have two of them, one for version 9.3 and 9.4. I changed some values in 9.3 version, and everything is working now. Thanks.

Comment: You should write up the changes you made as an answer, and accept it.